# Split pages and navigate in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a WPF page project, in which I've split the screen in two. On the left side, I have four clickable links / buttons.

Clicking on one of the links opens a corresponding page on the right side of the screen. There, options can be set. When a user uses the navigation bar on top of the screen, it should apply on the right side only.

Is this possible to do? What would be a better approach?

I'd like to know how to tell a page (part) which page to load. So that would make the right page dynamic?

Would it be better to split up the `Grid`? Or would a `DockPanel` be a better solution?

I've created a large `Window` in WPF, but I'd like to split up all these pages in a usefull navigation `Page`. So I have a bit of experience in using WPF and XAML. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firt you need to identify the components you want, mainly I see three components, the LeftSide navigation pane, the TopSide navigation pane and the MainContent pane. First lets talk about the MainContent pane, I think the best way for doing this is to use binding and date templates for making this dynamically. In your ViewModel, or DataContext, you need to have a property that represent the Content that you want to show in the MainContent, lets call it `MainContent`, then the MainContent View could be a `ContentControl` and set the property `Content` bindings to the ViewModel's `MainContent` property. In this way you only need to set the DataTemplate for each class item that you want to show. Other way could be to use a tab control and chage the ControlTemplate, this way is not dynamic because you need predefine all contents that you will show.

Now, for the navigation pane, you could use any control, for instance you could use a Radio button and change the ControlTemplate, and make the logic in the view model, using commands, for instance.

And now, the use of the `Grid` or `DockPanel` depends of what you want your application to do. If you want a dynamic width, you should to use a `Grid` with a `GridSplitter`, but if you want fixed width, you could to use a `DockPanel` due it is a bit more efficient/faster than the `Grid`.

Hope this answers helps, and not to be confused. Please feedback if any doubt.

---

**EDIT**

For instance, in the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object Content {get; set;}    //Here you must to raise the PropertyChanged event
    private ICommand _showSummaryCommand
    public ICommand ShowSummaryCommand
    {
         get { return new _showSummaryCommand ?? (_showSummaryCommand = new SomeCommandImplementation((sender,e)=>{Content = new SummaryViewModel()},true))}    //most of commands implementations recive two parameters, an delegate to execute and a bool delegate for can excecute
    }
}
```

and for the view, in some resource dictionary:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ViewModels:SummaryViewModel}">
    <DataGrid>
        <!--Here goes what ever you want to show for instace-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="descriptionText" Text={Binding Description}/>
    </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and in the place where you will to show all the contents

```
<!--....-->
    <ContentControl Content={Binding Content}/>
<!--....-->
```

Hope this code helps a bit more :)

Comment: I've filled in all the subpages and bound all the data accordingly. I'm now stuck on the very first part: my content page. When I have a grid at the left with the navigation buttons, how can I load a different .xaml in the right grid (or page, or..?)?

Comment: For instance, suppose you have a button that shows a summary content. Then in your view model you must have a ICommand called (for instace) ShowSummaryCommand, and this command the only that will do is set in the Content property, an object of type SummaryViewModel. Then you must have an DataTemplate for this SummaryViewModel where you will set what to show. I will make an edit to show better...